# General number field sieve function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have some questions about the General number field sieve - function on which I can't find an answer on the internet.

**In general:**

The GNFS-function $f(n)$ with $n$ the number for which we search the factorisation shows the complexity of that factorisation:

[image]

The GNFS-function gives the next aproxiations for the strength of RSA-moduli:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. $n$ is the number for which we search the factorisation, but is this number a number in base 10 or in bits? Because the table gives values in bits?
2. What is the meaning of the $o(1)$?
3. How much digits has an RSA-modulus of size 1024 in base 10?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: The base does not really matter as it only changes n by a constant factor. The number of digits in base 10 is about the number of bits times $\log_{10}(2)$ which is between 1/3 and 1/4.

Comment: @Moo And what does the 1 mean in o(1)? What's the difference with o(2)? Why do you calculate $2^{1024}$ as a power of 2?

Comment: @LeneCoenen Look up little oh notation.

Comment: @Moo "The modulus size in your list is given in bits, that is why I use $2^x$" --> Ok but why the number 2? The options are 0 and 1, but you still use 1 of them? & I still do not see how you can calculate the value of o(1)?

Comment: @Moo Much more clear! But I can only find numbers from 0 up to 15? I eddited the question.

Comment: @Moo So wat you are saying is that the value of o(1) in the formula can't be given?

Comment: $o(1)$ is not a value, it's an asymptotic notation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71737/discussion-between-lene-coenen-and-ian).